# google apps api audit only outgoing email

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I'm trying to set an email audit monitor only for the outgoing mails (sent items).
I got the API working using "GAM" or "C#" but I can only handle incoming and outgoing together.

On the Google framework for .Net there are only the following options:

```
MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
MonitorLevel.HEADER_ONLY;
```

What I'm looking for, is something more like the nochats / nodrafts on the GAM.

As default it seems like it send the incoming even if I don't write the following line on my code at all:

```
monitor.IncomingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
```

I've looked at the Google API website but couldn't see any list of all commands.
What I can say for sure, is that on the Google API .Net framework the only value allow for the monitor.IncomingEmailMonitorLevel are FULL_MESSAGE / HEADER_ONLY.

I've already read all the information on the following link:
[Google Apps Email Audit API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-audit/)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks from advanced,

NAIH

Answer (score 0):

You can see the exact XML that GAM is sending by creating a file called debug.gam in the same directory as gam.exe or gam.py. This may help you to figure out what changes your app or library need to make.

incoming and outgoing monitoring cannot be turned off, they can only be set to HEADERS_ONLY.